# Novak Infusionsoft SDK. How to retrieve all the information of all the Contacts at once?

Tags: php, api, sdk, infusionsoft

I am using the novak infusionsoft SDK.
             Is there a way to retrieve all the information of all the users on my infusionsoft account all at once?

```
$contacts = Infusionsoft_DataService::query(new Infusionsoft_Contact(), array('Id' => 11));
print_r($contacts );
```

This only retrieves the Contact with the Id of 11. I would like to retrieve all of them all at once.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All at once no. Infusionsoft puts a limit to the number of contacts you can get out of it in once call. I believe the upper limit is 1000 at a time for one page. You can keep incrementing the page number until you receive a page less than 1000 (you know that would be the last page).

It looks like the novak sdk supports this with the query function.

```
public static function query($object, $queryData, $limit = 1000, $page = 0, $returnFields = false, Infusionsoft_App $app = null)
    {
        $app = parent::getObjectOrDefaultAppIfNull($app, $object);
        if(!$returnFields){
            $returnFields = $object->getFields();
        }
        $params = array(
            $object->getTable(),
            (int) $limit,
            (int) $page,
            $queryData,
            $returnFields
        );
        $records = $app->send('DataService.query', $params, true);
        return self::_returnResults(get_class($object), $app->getHostName(), $records, $returnFields);
    }
```

Link to the DataService file:
https://github.com/novaksolutions/infusionsoft-php-sdk/blob/master/Infusionsoft/DataService.php